# protein secondary structure matching/comparison scoring

Tags: proteins, python, statistics, secondary-structure

I want to compare two secondary structures of aligned proteins. I do not know exactly how to do it well.

Example:

```
EEEEEEEEEEETTTTTTHCTTTEEECTTTEEECTTECTCCCHHHHHHHHHCHCCTHHEEEETTTEEECTTTEEECTTTEEC

EEEHHHHHHHTTTTTTTTCTTHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHEEEECCCCCCCCCCEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

Example of matching:

```
EEEEEEEEEEETTTTTTHCTTTEEECTTTEEECTTECTCCCHHHHHHHHHCHCCTHHEEEETTTEEECTTTEEECTTTEEC
|||        |||||| |||                    |||||||||     ||||||      |   |||    ||
EEEHHHHHHHTTTTTTTTCTTHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH----HHEEEECCCCCCCCCCEEEEEEEEEE
```

Hypothetically: 50% aligned - > score 0.5 - >  thats scoring is wrong:

```
EEEEEEEEEEETTTTTTHCTTTEEECTTTEEECTTECTCCCHHHHHHHHHCHCCTHHEEEETTTEEECTTTEEECTTTEEC
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
EEEEEEEEEEETTTTTTHCTTTEEECTTTEEECTTECTCCCHEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

This case will have similar score...

This is a puzzle for me, I don't know how to approach it technically.

Comment: Normally 3D structures of protein are compared and the RSMD is reported. How did you get your SS, with JPred or from PDBs? Comparing SS might result in some biases: if one of the two protein is getting used as a template for the other say or if both are from PDBs but the SS was called different (if so, use DSS on both). Also note that JPred is like 75% accurate at best.

Comment: @MatteoFerla I suspect that these are predicted secondary structures.

Comment: @James Exactly my worry (I see a helix of a single AA in a coil). The solution is straightforward, but I am not sure how one could add error estimates to said solutions, which seems like a must...

Comment: I suppose using data from JPred, PSIPRED, SPIDER2 and doing the 9 pairwise alignments would suffice on a push.

Comment: @MatteoFerla I agree. In lieu of a structure, usually, a meta-prediction would suffice. I think MTG should add why the sequences are being aligned. I think different tools should be used depending on if they are checking to see how much secondary structure prediction error is in a sequence compared to a reference sequence, or if they are checking secondary structure as a proxy for structural divergence.

Comment: It is a predicted SS with GOR method. I try to add sorting by SS to my algorihtm. First version will use garnier (emboss) method. Sequences are aligned because program align similar sequences. Then I add SS to check aligned proteins (additional validation). I plan to use spider or jpred in future.

Comment: In summary, this is a very provisional analysis, providing a starting point to further de novo prediction methods. We all assume the crystal structures are not present here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey i solve this simply by use of SOV alghoritm. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/319526145_A_modified_definition_of_Sov_a_segment-based_measure_for_protein_secondary_structure_prediction_assessment

cheers